# changing state of document.readyState to "complete" after downloading file via PHP's header('Content-Disposition: attachment...'

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer, readystate

My question is this: after downloading a file via PHP's `header('Content-Disposition: attachment`... technique, the webpage that originated the download has a `document.readyState` value of `interactive`.

I would expect this to be `complete` instead, as the downloading is complete.

Am I missing something, or is this the expected behavior?

If the latter, then is there any way to reset the `document.readyState` back to `complete`?

(This is using Internet Explorer, if it makes a difference...)

---

**Background:**

I have some JavaScript functions that I want active only when the page finishes loading, so I use

```
if( document.readyState != "complete" ) return;
```

at their start to achieve this goal. This works properly with the page loading, as `document.readyState` is `interactive` while loading progressively, and is `complete` only upon completion of the page load.

Later in the page, I present a link which sends the user to the below PHP code to allow download of the data loaded:

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=Shift-JIS' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );
$output = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
//write to file output... 
fclose( $output );
```

Now, pressing on this link causes `document.readyState` to be first `loading` and then `interactive`, but the state stays there, never moving to `complete`, thus disabling the earlier JavaScript functions...

---

I am at a loss of why this is so, and would appreciate any help, in any direction.

Comment: The *first* time your page has a `readyState` of `complete`, you know it has loaded fully and your scripts can run. When the user clicks a link that doesn't move away from the page (such as a page that only performs a file download) you could ignore the resulting readyState. So instead of checking the `readyState` in all your scripts, you could check whether the page has *ever* been in the `complete` `readyState`. (The rationale behind setting the `readyState` to `interactive` could be that technically, a different page has loaded, but was never rendered, and didn't make it into the history.)

Comment: @bzlm : I've resorted to setting a global flag to `true` once the page has finished loading (called from `window.onload`, which is what I believe to be an equivalent of checking if the page has reached the `complete` `readyState`), and to use that flag to determine the other scripts' availabilities. This seems to be working--thanks for the help, and if you'd like, make that an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @bzlm : but as for the rationale behind why the `readyState` stays `interactive`, I am still unsure... testing other similar links that "load" different pages without actually moving keep the `readyState` as `complete`... try here https://jsfiddle.net/mw6r013b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *first* time your page has a `readyState` of `complete`, you know it has loaded fully and your scripts can run. When the user clicks a link that doesn't move away from the page (such as a page that only performs a file download) you could ignore the resulting `readyState`. So instead of checking the `readyState` in all your scripts, you could check whether the page has *ever* been in the `complete` `readyState`.

The rationale behind setting the `readyState` to `interactive` could be that technically, a different page has loaded, but was never rendered, and didn't make it into the history. But I'm just guessing. As you've seen in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mw6r013b/), the behavior seems inconsistent.